# How to convert img url to BASE64 string in HTML on one method chain by using LINQ or Rx

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, system.reactive

I found I could generate XDocument object from html by using SgmlReader.SL.
https://bitbucket.org/neuecc/sgmlreader.sl/

The code is like this.

```
public XDocument Html(TextReader reader)
{
    XDocument xml;
    using (var sgmlReader = new SgmlReader { DocType = "HTML", CaseFolding = CaseFolding.ToLower, InputStream = reader })
    {
        xml = XDocument.Load(sgmlReader);
    }
    return xml;
}
```

Also we can get src attributes of img tags from the XDocument object.

```
var ns = xml.Root.Name.Namespace;

var imgQuery = xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "img")
    .Select(e => new
        {
            Link = e.Attribute("src").Value
        });
```

And, we can download and convert stream data of image to BASE64 string.

```
public static string base64String;

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));  //image url from src attribute
wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);

void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[32768];
            int read = e.Result.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            if (read > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buf, 0, read);
            }
            else { break; }
        }
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    }
}
```

So, What I'd like to do is bellow steps. I'd like to do bellow steps in one method chain like LINQ or Reactive Extensions.

1. Get src attributes of img tags from XDocument object.
2. Get image datas from urls.
3. Generate BASE64 string from image datas.
4. Replace src attributes by BASE64 string.

The simplest source and output are here.

- Before

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <img src='http://image.com/image.jpg' />
      <img src='http://image.com/image2.png' />
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- After

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw...' />
              <img src='data:image/png;base64,iSDoske...' />
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Does anyone know the solution for this?

I'd like to ask experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both LINQ and Rx are designed to promote transformations that result in new objects, not ones that modify existing objects, but this is still doable.  You have already done the first step, breaking the task into parts.  The next step is to make composable functions that implement those steps.

1) You mostly have this one already, but we should probably keep the elements around to update later.

```
public IEnumerable<XElement> GetImages(XDocument document)
{
    var ns = document.Root.Name.Namespace;
    return document.Root.Descendants(ns + "img");
}
```

2)  This seems to be where you have hit a wall from the composability point of view.  To start, lets make a `FromEventAsyncPattern` observable generator.  There are already ones for the Begin/End async pattern and standard events, so this will come out somewhere in between.

```
public IObservable<TEventArgs> FromEventAsyncPattern<TDelegate, TEventArgs> 
    (Action method, Action<TDelegate> addHandler, Action<TDelegate> removeHandler
    ) where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    return Observable.Create<TEventArgs>(
        obs =>
        {
            //subscribe to the handler before starting the method
            var ret = Observable.FromEventPattern<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(addHandler, removeHandler)
                                .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
                                .Take(1) //do this so the observable completes
                                .Subscribe(obs);
            method(); //start the async operation
            return ret;
        }
    );
}
```

Now we can use this method to turn the downloads into observables.  Based on your usage, I think you could also use `DownloadDataAsync` on the WebClient instead.

```
public IObservable<byte[]> DownloadAsync(Uri address)
{
    return Observable.Using(
             () => new System.Net.WebClient(),
             wc =>
             {
                return FromEventAsyncPattern<System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler,
                                             System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs>
                          (() => wc.DownloadDataAsync(address),
                           h => wc.DownloadDataCompleted += h,
                           h => wc.DownloadDataCompleted -= h
                          )
                       .Select(e => e.Result);
                //for robustness, you should probably check the error and cancelled
                //properties instead of assuming it finished like I am here.
             });
}
```

EDIT: As per your comment, you appear to be using Silverlight, where `WebClient` is not `IDisposable` and does not have the method I was using.  To deal with that, try something like:

```
public IObservable<byte[]> DownloadAsync(Uri address)
{
    var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    var eap = FromEventAsyncPattern<OpenReadCompletedEventHandler,
                                    OpenReadCompletedEventArgs>(
                 () => wc.OpenReadAsync(address),
                 h => wc.OpenReadCompleted += h,
                 h => wc.OpenReadCompleted -= h);
    return from e in eap
           from b in e.Result.ReadAsync()
           select b;
}
```

You will need to find an implementation of `ReadAsync` to read the stream.  You should be able to find one pretty easily, and the post was long enough already so I left it out.

3 & 4) Now we are ready to put it all together and update the elements.  Since step 3 is so simple, I'll just merge it in with step 4.

```
public IObservable<Unit> ReplaceImageLinks(XDocument document)
{
    return (from element in GetImages(document)
            let address = new Uri(element.Attribute("src").Value)
            select (From data in DownloadAsync(address)
                    Select Convert.ToBase64String(data)
                   ).Do(base64 => element.Attribute("src").Value = base64)
           ).Merge()
            .IgnoreElements()
            .Select(s => Unit.Default); 
            //select doesn't really do anything as IgnoreElements eats all
            //the values, but it is needed to change the type of the observable.
            //Task may be more appropriate here.
}
```

Comment: It's incredible! I really appreciate your response. I tried to understand your code and implement in my app(WP app).

I'd like to ask a question. About DownloadAsync method, I cannot use Observable.Using method because of bellow error.
-----
The type 'System.Net.WebClient' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResource' in the generic type or method 'System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Using<TSource,TResource>(System.Func<TResource>, System.Func<TResource,System.IObservable<TSource>>)'. 
-----

I didn't see this error WPF app. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @ShingoTada I assume you meant Silverlight, where `WebClient` does not implement `IDisposable`.  In that case, get rid of the using call, but leave the rest of the code in that method.

Comment: In your `IObservable<byte[]>` code, should the first usage of `wc` be `wc =>`?

Comment: @ShingoTada After looking some more, I realized the Silverlight WebClient is more different than just not implementing IDisposable. I updated the answer with a starting point for Silverlight.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth Thanks a lot. I found the "WebClient problem". So, I chose HttpWebRequest. This also works.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth Hi, I'm testing your sample now. In last sample code, It seem not to be executed "let address = new Uri(element.Attribute("src").Value)". It doesn't stop here if I put breakpoint. Do you have any idea??

Comment: @ShingoTada The only thing that comes to mind is that the document does not have any image tags in the appropriate namespace.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth Thanks. I'll check the document, and I try to change the url to another.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth I confirmed by uring bellow code that GetImages(document) method returned img tags as IEnumerable correctly.                     foreach (var img in GetImages(xml))
                    {
                        string tag = img.ToString();
                    }I try another way.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth I also think your code is correct. I think the problem is my env issue.